# RestyGWT- custom dispatcher doesn't call registered filters

Tags: java, gwt, resty-gwt

I am trying to write my custom dispatcher for resty gwt.

My dispatcher `RestyDispatcher` will contain two filters:

- `BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter` (which will add to each request security token),
- `ForbiddenDispatcherFilter` (which will contains callback `ForbiddenDispatcherCallback`)- his job is to redirect to login page if user is not logged in.

I have problem, that my filters are registered by gwt/restygwt, unfortunatelly they don't work.

Here is code:

**gin client module**

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    install(new DefaultModule.Builder().defaultPlace(Routing.PAGE.url).errorPlace(Routing.PAGE.url).unauthorizedPlace(Routing.LOGIN.url).tokenFormatter(RouteTokenFormatter.class).build());
    install(new AppModule());

    bind(CurrentUser.class).in(Singleton.class);
    bind(UserLoginGatekeeper.class).in(Singleton.class);

    // Load and inject CSS resources
    bind(ResourceLoader.class).asEagerSingleton();

    bind(RestyGwtConfig.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}
```

**RestyGwtConfig**

```
public class RestyGwtConfig {
    public RestyGwtConfig() {
    final Dispatcher dispatcher = new RestyDispatcher();
    GWT.log("--> RestyGwtConfig -> setDispatcher");
    Defaults.setDispatcher(dispatcher);

    UserCredentials.INSTANCE.setUserName("ronan");
    UserCredentials.INSTANCE.setPassword("password");
    }

    static {
    GWT.log("--> RestyGwtConfig -> setServiceRoot");
    Defaults.setServiceRoot(new Resource(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()).resolve("../../cms/services").getUri());
    }

}
```

**RestyDispatcher**

```
public class RestyDispatcher extends DefaultFilterawareDispatcher {

    public RestyDispatcher() {
    addFilter(new ForbiddenDispatcherFilter());
    GWT.log("--> RestyDispatcher -> RestyDispatcher -> addFilter -> ForbiddenDispatcherFilter");
    addFilter(new BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter());
    GWT.log("--> RestyDispatcher -> RestyDispatcher -> addFilter -> BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter");
    }

    @Override
    public Request send(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) throws RequestException {
    GWT.log("SimpleDispatcher.Request.send.start");
    Request send = builder.send();
    GWT.log("SimpleDispatcher.Request.send.done");

    return send;
    }

}
```

**ForbiddenDispatcherFilter**

```
public class ForbiddenDispatcherFilter implements DispatcherFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) {
    GWT.log("--> ForbiddenDispatcherFilter -> filter -> setCallback");
    builder.setCallback(new ForbiddenDispatcherCallback(method));
    return true;
    }

}
```

**ForbiddenDispatcherCallback**

```
public class ForbiddenDispatcherCallback implements RequestCallback {
    protected RequestCallback requestCallback;

    public ForbiddenDispatcherCallback(Method method) {
    GWT.log("_________> ForbiddenDispatcherCallback " + method.toString());

    this.requestCallback = method.builder.getCallback();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
    GWT.log("_________> ForbiddenDispatcherCallback -> onResponseReceived");

    GWT.log(response.getStatusText() + response.getStatusCode());
    if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.SC_FORBIDDEN || response.getStatusCode() == Response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
        // make a hard redirect to login page
        Window.Location.assign("#/login");
    } else {
        requestCallback.onResponseReceived(request, response);
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
    GWT.log("_________> ForbiddenDispatcherCallback -> onError");
    requestCallback.onError(request, exception);
    }

}
```

**BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter**

```
final class BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter implements DispatcherFilter {

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    @Override
    public boolean filter(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) {
    String basicAuthHeaderValue = createBasicAuthHeader(UserCredentials.INSTANCE.getUserName(), UserCredentials.INSTANCE.getPassword());
    builder.setHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, basicAuthHeaderValue);

    return true;
    }

    private String createBasicAuthHeader(String userName, String password) {
    String credentials = userName + ":" + password;
    String encodedCredentials = credentials;
    return AUTHORIZATION_HEADER + ": Basic " + encodedCredentials;

    }
}
```

When I run app I get this logs in web browser console:

```
--> RestyGwtConfig -> setServiceRoot
SuperDevModeLogger.java:71--> RestyDispatcher -> RestyDispatcher -> addFilter -> ForbiddenDispatcherFilter
SuperDevModeLogger.java:71--> RestyDispatcher -> RestyDispatcher -> addFilter -> BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter
SuperDevModeLogger.java:71--> RestyGwtConfig -> setDispatcher
```

So I assume that my Dispatcher, whith does 2 filters is registered correctly. Unfortunatelly I do not see log from `ForbiddenDispatcherFilter` saying that it set my callback `ForbiddenDispatcherCallback`. I also don't see any log from mentioned callback.

When I execute any resty service, I am getting logs entries:

`SimpleDispatcher.Request.send.start SuperDevModeLogger.java:71`

`SimpleDispatcher.Request.send.done XMLHttpRequest.java:305`

`POST http://localhost:8080/cms/services/authenticated/testService/setInfo 401 (Unauthorized)`

Cause I didn't found much about it in documentation, To achieve this I've base on those examples:

- [ars-codia blog](http://ars-codia.raphaelbauer.com/2011/11/how-to-write-custom-callback-filter-for.html)
- [ronanquillevere blog](https://ronanquillevere.github.io/2014/04/11/restygwt-basic-auth.html#.Vrz0I3UrKVM)

but none of this where enought specified. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually override `send` method in `RestyDispatcher` class, So my implementation have to manually execute `super.send(method, builder)`. Or I should not override `send` method at all.

So `RestyDispatcher` it should look like this:

```
public class RestyDispatcher extends DefaultFilterawareDispatcher {

    public RestyDispatcher() {
        addFilter(new ForbiddenDispatcherFilter());
        addFilter(new BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter());
    }

    @Override
    public Request send(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) throws RequestException {
         return super.send(method, builder);
    }

}
```

or

```
public class RestyDispatcher extends DefaultFilterawareDispatcher {

    public RestyDispatcher() {
    addFilter(new ForbiddenDispatcherFilter());
    addFilter(new BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is to execute manually `filter` method.
I don't know is it good solution. I assume that this is a **bug**, cause `filter` method should be called by RestyGWT, as it is declared in `interface DispatcherFilter` and implemented in `DefaultFilterawareDispatcher` class as follow:

```
package org.fusesource.restygwt.client.dispatcher;
public class DefaultFilterawareDispatcher implements FilterawareDispatcher {

   @Override
    public Request send(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) throws RequestException {
        for (DispatcherFilter f : dispatcherFilters) {
            if (!f.filter(method, builder)) {
                // filter returned false, no continue
                if (GWT.isClient() && LogConfiguration.loggingIsEnabled()) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DefaultFilterawareDispatcher.class.getName())
                            .fine(f.getClass() + " told me not to continue filtering for: "
                                    + builder.getHTTPMethod() + " " + builder.getUrl());
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
        return builder.send();
    }
}
```

Here is my code implemenation:

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(RestyGwtConfig.class).asEagerSingleton();
        install(new DefaultModule.Builder().defaultPlace(Routing.PAGE.url).errorPlace(Routing.PAGE.url).unauthorizedPlace(Routing.LOGIN.url).tokenFormatter(RouteTokenFormatter.class).build());
        install(new AppModule());
        bind(CurrentUser.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(IsAdminGatekeeper.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(UserLoginGatekeeper.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RestyGwtConfig {
    static {
        Defaults.setDispatcher(new RestyDispatcher());
        Defaults.setServiceRoot(new Resource(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()).resolve("../../cms/services").getUri());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RestyDispatcher extends DefaultFilterawareDispatcher {

    public RestyDispatcher() {
        addFilter(new ForbiddenDispatcherFilter());
        addFilter(new BasicAuthHeaderDispatcherFilter());
    }
    @Override
    public Request send(Method method, RequestBuilder builder) throws RequestException {
        for (DispatcherFilter e : this.dispatcherFilters) {
            e.filter(method, builder);
        }
    return builder.send();
    }
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.